# R functions that output datasets

Tags: r, function, dataframe, output

I am a bit new to R and am trying to use a function to output a dataframe.  I have several dataframes that need deduplication.  Each record in the data frame has an index variable (RecID) and a patient ID (PatID).  If patients are listed multiple times in the dataframe, I want to choose the record largest RecID.

I want to be able to change this data frame:

```
PatID   RecID
1       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
3       5
4       6
```

Into this dataframe

```
PatID    RecID
1        2
2        3
3        5
4        6
```

I can use the following code to successfully deduplicate the dataframe.

```
df <- df[order(df$PatID, -df$RecID),]
df <- df[ !duplicated(df$PatID), ]
```

I created a function with this code so I can apply my deduplication scheme across multiple data frames easily.

```
dedupit <- function(x) {
    x <- x[order(x$PatID, -x$RecID),]
    x <- x[ !duplicated(x$PatID), ]
  }
```

However, when I put use the code `dedupit(df)`, it does not create a new df dataframe with deduplicated records.The function won't output the final dataframes or any of the intermediate dataframes. Is there a way to have functions output dataframes?

Comment: you need to return from the function. do `return(x)` as the last line in your function defn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put return(x) at the end of your function.